# .NET TabIndex navigation didn't start from the beginning when it reach the last one

Tags: c#, .net, tabs, tabindex

I have application in which I have tabindex navigation. I'm wondered why the application didn't continue from the first index when reaching the last one and the user clicks the "tab" key. Do somebody know how I can have this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should review your situation. Selected object changes to first one  after the last one but:

- Your code/settings somehow disallow that,
- Control may change to some sub-controls. Like a grid in a page.